# XML converting to JSON, I want to make a dynamic solution - using python dictonary

Tags: python, json, xml

I am asking you all for help with converting XML to JSON. I am using dictonary.

my code looks like this

```
import json
import xmltodict

with open('xmlskuska.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

doc['Invoice']['ID'] = doc['Invoice'].pop('cbc:ID')
doc['Invoice']['IssueDate'] = doc['Invoice'].pop('cbc:IssueDate')
doc['Invoice']['OrderReference'] = doc['Invoice'].pop('cac:OrderReference')
doc['Invoice']['OrderReference']['ID'] = doc['Invoice']['OrderReference'].pop('cbc:ID')
doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine'] = doc['Invoice'].pop('cac:InvoiceLine')
doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine']['Price'] = doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine'].pop('cac:Price')
doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine']['Price']['PriceAmount'] = doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine']['Price'].pop('cbc:PriceAmount')
doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine']['Price']['BaseQuantity'] = doc['Invoice']['InvoiceLine']['Price'].pop('cbc:BaseQuantity')

app_json = json.dumps(doc)
print(app_json)

with open('skuska.json', 'w') as json_file:
json.dump(doc, json_file)
```

this is my XML file xmlskuska.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
        <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:IssueDate>2009-12-15</cbc:IssueDate>
        <cac:OrderReference>
             <cbc:ID>123</cbc:ID>
        <cac:OrderReference>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0.75</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
            </cac:Price>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

The thing is that the output of the file has structure which i don't want. I want nice JSON structure.

I Am getting this:

```
{"Invoice": {"@xmlns": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2", "@xmlns:cac": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2", "@xmlns:cbc": "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2", "ID": "TOSL108", "IssueDate": "2009-12-15", "OrderReference": {"ID": "123"}, "InvoiceLine": {"Price": {"PriceAmount": {"@currencyID": "EUR", "#text": "0.75"}, "BaseQuantity": {"@unitCode": "C62", "#text": "1"}}}}}
```

The second thing which I want to ask is, how to make a dynamic solution with this conversion? I don't want to make all this section with changing value of dictorany, for example "doc['Invoice']['ID'] = doc['Invoice'].pop('cbc:ID')".
I mean that I want to use many more XML files to conversion, not just this one I shared.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: for getting json in a beautiful structure use `json.dump(doc, json_file,indent = 2)`

Comment: thanks a lot, now I have a beautiful json

Comment: Your xml is not valid. `<cac:OrderReference>` --> `</cac:OrderReference>`

Answer (score 0):

See below (no external library is used)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pprint

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
        <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:IssueDate>2009-12-15</cbc:IssueDate>
        <cac:OrderReference>
             <cbc:ID>123</cbc:ID>
        </cac:OrderReference>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0.75</cbc:PriceAmount>
                <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="C62">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
            </cac:Price>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {}
def xml2dict(root,data):
    lst = list(root)
    for e in lst:
        idx = e.tag.rfind('}')
        if idx != -1:
            _tag = e.tag[idx+1:]
            if e.text.strip():
                data[_tag] = e.text
            else:
                data[_tag] = {}
                xml2dict(e,data[_tag])

xml2dict(root,data)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

output:

```
{'ID': 'TOSL108',
 'InvoiceLine': {'Price': {'BaseQuantity': '1', 'PriceAmount': '0.75'}},
 'IssueDate': '2009-12-15',
 'OrderReference': {'ID': '123'}}
```